# Baking Sirloin in Oven on Pizza?

Tags: baking, meat, oven, pizza, steak

Ordinarily when we make pizzas we throw all of our toppings on and then put raw chicken right on the pizza. Put it in the oven at 425 for about 30 minutes and it's good to go.

This week, the supermarket was out of the chicken we normally buy, so we decided to mix it up and try sirloin.

If we try the same thing with the sirloin (putting it on the pizza raw and cooking it at 425 for 30 minutes) will it be safe to eat? Will it get tough and flavorless being in that long? Would it be a better idea to pan-fry the sirloin and then put it on the pizza after we pull it out of the oven?

**EDIT**

Took Navajo Dreamchild's advice. Ended up using a marinade with pineapple and soy sauce (who says pineapple's not allowed on pizza). Sauteed the sirloin to just about medium rare and then threw it onto the almost done pizza with a little more cheese before putting it back in the oven to finish.

I wish I'd taken a picture to post here, but it was all gone before we knew it. Absolutely delicious--thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that if you were using fresh sirloin and the pieces were small enough you would be alright using the method you mentioned. I would think that if you were to pre-cook your sirloin and then cook it on top of the pizza for that long you might get tough sirloin. I would suggest cooking the sirloin until just about done, while the pizza is cooking then putting the sirloin on the pizza (I would add a little more cheese at this point- but that's just me), and giving it 2-3 minutes under the broiler to melt the cheese and cook the sirloin the rest of the way. 
To avoid losing the flavor of the meat, you should marinade it for at least 30 minutes and season well before you precook or put on your pizza(use a meat tenderizer in your marinade to avoid tough meat- vinegar or pineapple juice works well.) Good Luck- I hope it turns out delicious.